# Vue3 + TS: How to fix type 'never' for ref of empty array?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am trying to copy a component from one of my old vue projects that only uses JS into a TS/Vue Project and came across a few hurdles.

```
<script lang="ts">
import { computed, ref } from "vue";
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
export default defineComponent ({
setup() {

const todo = ref("");
const todos = ref([]);
let id = 0;
const numberOfCompletedTodos = computed(
  () => todos.value.filter((todo) => todo.completed).length
);
function addTodo() {
  todos.value.push({
    id: id,
    title: todo.value.trim(),
    completed: false,
  });
  todo.value = "";
  id++;
}
function removeTodo(index) {
  todos.value.splice(index, 1);
}
...
...
...
</script>
```

Because of the ref([]) I am getting the following errors:

```
- Argument of type '{ id: number; title: string; completed: boolean; }' is not 
assignable to parameter of type 'never'.ts(2345)

- Property 'completed' does not exist on type 'never'.

- Parameter 'index' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ref` function is generic - it can infer the type of the value you want to store in the returned reference. Since you pass an empty array, the type that is inferred is `never[]`, which means an array that will never have any elements. This is obviously not what you want. You could initialize the `ref` with an array that has a Todo, but that's not ideal.

In this case, you need to tell TypeScript that you intend to store Todos in this array. You can do this by passing a type parameter to the `ref` function. Define a `type` or an `interface` for Todo and pass it like this:

```js
type Todo = {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  completed: boolean;
}

const todos = ref<Todo[]>([]);
```

You can also do this inline:

```js
const todos = ref<{ id: number; title: string; completed: boolean }[]>([]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would create an interface for that. Also the usage of the generic `ref<>` make things easier.

ITodo.ts

```
export interface ITodo {
        id: number;
        title: string;
        completed: boolean;
    }
```

Component.vue

```
<script lang="ts">
import { computed, ref } from "vue";
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
export default defineComponent ({
    setup() {
        const todo = ref<ITodo|undefined>(undefined);
        const todos = ref<ITodo[]>([]);
        let id = 0;
        const numberOfCompletedTodos = computed(
            () => todos.value.filter((todo) => todo.completed).length
        );
        function addTodo() {
            todos.value.push(todo.value);
            todo.value = undefined;
            id++;
        }
        function removeTodo(index) {
            todos.value.splice(index, 1);
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue when working with a reactive store in Vue.js, albeit in a slightly different scenario. Simply adding an interface didn't resolve the issue. However, explicitly assigning a type using **[] as Apple[]** proved to be the solution.

```
interface Apple {
  text: string;
}
interface AppleStore {
  apples: Apple[];
}
export const appleStore: AppleStore = reactive({
  apples: [] as Apple[]
})
```

Hope it helps. As always, enjoy.